# Import suggestions by Typescript / VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have a file `a.ts` with 4 named imports:

```
export const one = 1
export const two = 2
export const three = 3
export const four = 4
```

Then I have a file `b.ts` when I want to import some variables from `a.ts`.

```
import {} from './a.ts'
```

Is there a way to get suggestions from Typescript or VS Code when I click inside the curly brackets? Something like pop-up menu, which lists all the possible imports that could be done from that file.

Answer (score 1):

Place the cursor inside the curly braces in the import line and try hitting CTRL-Space in your IDE. In WebStorm IDE, this shows possible imports.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a list of a tens of snippets (both self-made and from VS Code extensions), when I perform this action and the imports are staffed to the bottom of the list. Is there any way to only get the import suggestions when I click inside the curly brackets?